# Error of EntityPropertyMappingAttribute

Tags: wcf

I am using this LOC

```
[EntityPropertyMappingAttribute("FieldName", SyndicationItemProperty.Summary,         SyndicationTextContentKind.Plaintext, true)]
```

but i am getting error like "The type or namespace name EntityPropertyMappingAttribute could not be found are you missing asse,bly reference..and also included

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Data.Services.Common;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using FluorineFx;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
```

mentioned namespace..

Please help to short out this issue